I want to find a movie about people that get into dreams
When I was about 10 years old I saw a home recorded VHS tape with one movie that was overriden on the end, but I remember it was about a world where people could enter inside each other dreams and fight to death using a machine.
I also remeber there was a bet scheme where if they die inside the dream, their lives became something that worth a lot of money.
One of the characters looked like Pat Morita, but on that I can maybe be fooled by memory.
Any help will be appreciated!

"When I was about 10 years old.."  That might be useful information if we knew when you were 10 years old..

@AndrewThompson Hats off man :-) HAHA you've made my day

Voting to close this instead of answering it again. Other than confusing dreams with VR, this sounds like Timemaster from 1995 with Pat Morita. If I'm wrong, please let me know.

@BrettFromLA Is that another joke to make me laugh ?? :-) I didn't ask the question my friend. Look up.

It's a duplicated question, the linked one is right. Timemaster (1995)
